# nested divs in precise number of rows and columns (for printing)

Tags: css

I'm getting an output consisting of multiple divs.

For browser view, I use flexbox to display the divs.

But for printing, I need a precise number of rows/columns : it should be 8 rows by 6 columns, where each div should be placed very exactly on the paper.

Is it possible, with just a bunch of divs, to display them in 8x6 for printing ?

The html looks like this :

```
<div class="labels"> 
   <div class="label">123</div>
   <div class="label">456</div>
   <div class="label">789</div>
   <div class="label">012</div>
   ...
</div>
```

CSS for browser view (exact positioning not important) :

```
div.labels {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Maybe I have to use some rules inside a `@media print { ... }` block, but I can't find out what.

Comment: Since you want the labels in 8 rows of 6 columns are you guaranteed to have exactly 46 labels in the `labels` div in all scenarios?

Comment: No, for each print, there will be between 1 and 46 labels.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add `flex: 0 0 16.67%` to `.label`, or does that work for you?

Comment: Great, I get rows of 6 divs using `flex: 0 0 16.66%` (instead of .67).  Thanks.   Is there also a way to evenly position the rows ?    Because now, only the colums are evenly distributed.   For instance, if I use the 48 labels (8x6), the 8 rows does not take the full page.